# How to use the the column as identifier

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I need to know  which row of a certain column starts with the letter "O".
I tried for this the query function.

I try to achieve this with a QUERY on a this Column. But the first row of the Column doesn't have a particular name. My question is how can I use the Column as identifier in a 'where query'
In this example I need to know in which row of column

```
=QUERY(A4:A30;"where columnA start with 'O'")
```

Comment: `where A ......`

Comment: "where A starts with 'O'"

Answer (score 0):

As [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322692/how-to-use-the-the-column-as-identifier#comment87665447_50322692) by @[JPV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889423/jpv):

```
=QUERY(A4:A30;"where A starts with 'O'")
```

However, with FILTER is shorter:

```
=filter(A4:A30;Left(A4:A30)="O")
```